# Android working with onInterceptTouchEvent

Tags: android, view, widget, onclick

I have two fragments, one over lapping the other.  See image below.  I extended the LinearLayout class and overrode onInterceptTouchEvent so if Fragment1 is touched Fragment2 would disappear, which is working as planned.  But my problem is there are some views in Fragment2 that when pressed would triggered Fragment1's onInterceptTouchEvent which is making Fragment2 disappear inadvertently. It seems like the views/widgets that are handling an onClick events in Fragment2 (ie listview, buttons, etc) are Not triggering Fragment1's onInterceptTouchEvent.  But any other views/widgets (ie TextView, ImageView, or blank space with in the layout) is triggering Fragment1's  onInterceptTouchEvent event.

My question.  How can I prevent all the views in Fragment2 from triggering Fragment1's onInterceptTouchEvent?

Makes senes?
Thanks for your help!

Bradley4

[image]

Comment: The widgets in Frag2 that were inadvertently triggering Fragment1's onInterceptTouchEvent I implmented their onClick and kept the body empty. this stopped the triggering of onInterceptTouchEvent.